# trouble installing gitlab docker image. permission denied error

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am trying to build gitlab using docker and keep getting this error message.

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb': Permission denied
```

it looks like `GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG` is the issue.

I don't know how to resolve the issue. Please help!

Comment: Can you provide some more detail like your docker file or the commands you are running when you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

It depends when you are getting the error message: on docker build or docker run.

In the latter case (runtime), you would need to mount your user folder (where you have the right to write) to GitLab container, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51322122/6309):

```
    --volume /Users/username/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
    --volume /Users/username/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
    --volume /Users/username/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
```

[Official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html#set-up-the-volumes-location):

> ### Set up the volumes location
>
> Before setting everything else, configure a new environment variable `$GITLAB_HOME` pointing to the directory where the configuration, logs, and data files will reside.
>
> Ensure that the directory exists and appropriate permission have been granted.
>
> For macOS users, use the user’s `$HOME/gitlab` directory:
>
> ```
> export GITLAB_HOME=$HOME/gitlab
> ```